# Error in package fancyvrb: Too many }'s

Tags: errors, minted, compilation-error, fancyvrb

When I include the package `fancyvrb` via `\usepackage{fancyvrb}` or other packages that make use of that package (for example `minted`), I get the error `Missing \endscname inserted` (line 535 of fancyvrb.sty) and `Too many }'s` (line 540 of fancyvrb.sty).

I believe this happened due to a system update I ran, though I'm not sure about this. The current fancyvrb version I have installed on my computer is Verison 4.1b.

Has anyone had the same problem? Do you have any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Parts of the compilation error:

```
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty
/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty:535: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \unhbox 
l.535 \define@key{FV}{file_ext}[.tex]
                                     {\def\FancyVerbFileExtension{#1}}
/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty:535: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \unhbox 
l.535 \define@key{FV}{file_ext}[.tex]
                                     {\def\FancyVerbFileExtension{#1}}
/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty:540: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \unhbox 
l.540 \fvset{defineactive,file_ext=.tex}
                                        

/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty:540: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.540 \fvset{defineactive,file_ext=.tex}
                                        
/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty:540: Extra \endcsname.
\KV@split ...csname \KV@prefix \@tempa \endcsname 
                                                  \ifx \@tempc \relax \KV@er...
l.540 \fvset{defineactive,file_ext=.tex}
                                        
/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty:540: Use of \@tempc doesn't match its definition.
<recently read> {
                 
l.540 \fvset{defineactive,file_ext=.tex}
                                        
/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty:540: Too many }'s.
\KV@split ...after \@tempc \expandafter {\@tempb }
                                                  \relax \fi \fi \fi 
l.540 \fvset{defineactive,file_ext=.tex}
```

Comment: you should supply a test file that demonstrates the problem, so people can debug, but I would guess you have made `_` active with a definition that is not allowed in a csname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message you show suggests an issue with `_` and in fact this test document gives the same error

```
\documentclass{article}
\catcode`\_\active
\def_{\mbox{}}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Producing

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.535 \define@key{FV}{file_ext}[.tex]
                                     {\def\FancyVerbFileExtension{#1}}
?
```

It is best not to redefine `_` at all, but if you do redefine it, delay the redefinition until after the preamble to avoid breaking packages that assume standard settings.